# How can I read the accelerometer in my windows tablet with python?

Tags: python, windows, accelerometer

I have an accelerometer in my tablet, that I can read from within javascript.

How can I access this data in python? Is there some ctypes trickery I can use to call a windows 8 Sensor API function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Horrible hack - start up a webserver in `server.py`:

```py
import bottle
from threading import Thread

on_data = lambda alpha, beta, gamma: None

@bottle.route('/')
def handler():
    return bottle.static_file('index.html', '.')

@bottle.post('/data')
def handler():
    on_data(**bottle.request.json)

def data_handler(f):
    global on_data
    on_data = f
    return f

def go():
    t = Thread(target=lambda: bottle.run(quiet=True))
    t.start()
```

With this `index.html`:

```html
<script>
  window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function(eventData) {
    var d = {};
    ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma'].forEach(function(prop) {
      d[prop] = eventData[prop];
    })
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/data");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(d));
  }, false);
</script>
```

And use it as:

```
import server

@server.data_hander
def on_acc_data(alpha, beta, gamma):
    print alpha, beta, gamma

server.go()
```

After having opened `localhost:8080/` in the browser

Comment: I know this is old, but is there a direct way of reading the data with python (w./o the webserver)